# Front Camera should open as Default, But it works only few devices, Android studio

Tags: android, front-camera

I'm trying to add click image of user from Android mobile app in Android studio, and want open front camera always instead of back camera. But it only works on some devices and I want it to work with every device. Currently I'm using an OnePlus, which doesn't open the front camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

I've tried this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT); startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Camera information (default camera, orientation )  depends on each manufacturer. You might need to Get camera info first, check if a facing cam is available & then open it.

Answer (score 1):

The constant `Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT` was deprecated in Android API 23. You should use the constant `CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT` instead.

Try adding the following extra to the intent:

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
```

You can also use **CameraX** library to open the front camera:

```
val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
  val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
  val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT).build()
  val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector)

  // Start the camera preview
  camera.preview.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
  camera.startPreview()
}) { e -> e.printStackTrace() }
```